# react-table v6 multiple tables issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Good day
I have 2 tables side by side and I want them to act like one table with borders and scroll independently and, when my cursor goes over the 1 row in the first table I want to highlight 1 row in the second table
However this is done internally by react-table.
Any solutions how can I implement highlighting same row from both tables?
And I wonder about simultaneous vertical scroll, are there also any solutions in react way?

Don't want to add event listeners to tables like this

```
        firstTableBody.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
            const tablePosition = e.target.scrollTop;
            firstTableBody.scrollTop = tablePosition;
        });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-edgooj?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

ok, I did a highlight for all tables at once

For every table I add

```
getTrProps={rowProps}
```

and in `rowProps` I implement

```
const rowProps = useCallback((state, rowInfo) => {
    if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
        const isRowHovered = rowInfo.index === hoveredRow;
        return {
            style: {
                background: isRowHovered ? '#D1DDE1' : ''
            },
            onMouseEnter: () => {
                setHoveredRow(rowInfo.index)
            },
            onMouseLeave: () => {
                setHoveredRow(null)
            }
        }
    }
}, [hoveredRow]);
```

I really dunno why there is always such a poor documentation in all those libs